# Model with acts_as_tenant fails validation after Rails 5 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, multi-tenant, acts-as-tenant

rails 5.2.1 ruby 2.5.1

My Model

```
class InputForm < ApplicationRecord
 acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
end
```

InputForm.validators shows

```
#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x000000000baaae28
@attributes=[:tenant],
@options={:message=>:required}>
```

**This is not allowing me to create the InputForm without tenant.**

> Note : I don't have any config setup (config.require_tenant = true )
>   or file like config/initializers/acts_as_tenant.rb

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `optional: true` options when specifying acts_as_tenant?

```
class InputForm < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant :tenant, optional: true
end
```

OR

You can configure your rails 5 application like so

```
# config/application.rb
...
module YourProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    # Make the belongs_to value as false by default in Rails 5
    config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
    ...
  end
end
```

Responded here as well.

https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/issues/196#issuecomment-460605781